# NodeJS run program in a continuous loop

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a simplex (one way) chat application and this app needs to take a certain input and send it to a messaging queue and then at the receivers end.

The issue I'm facing is that whenever the app is run on my dev environment, it runs once and finishes execution immediately. How do I make it run in an infinite loop where it waits for the user to input certain things, runs it, and wait for the next set of input. I tried a while loop but it didn't work.

```
function printforme() {
    rl.question("message: ", function(answer) {
        console.log("Your message: ", answer);
        rl.close();
    });
}
printforme();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `rl.close()` and call yourself again to keep asking for more input:

```
function printforme() {
    rl.question("message: ", function(answer) {
        console.log("Your message: ", answer);
        // check if we're supposed to exit
        if (answer === "exit") {
            rl.close()
        } else {
            // ask for input again
            printforme();
        }
    });
}
printforme();
```

When you call `rl.close()`, there is nothing left for the nodejs app to do so it exits.  If you want to ask another question, then remove the `rl.close()` and call `printforme()` again from inside the `rl.question()` callback.  Because the callback is asynchronous, this will not create stack buildup.  The stack completely unwinds before the async callback is called.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!